# Фазы касания экрана в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, touch-event, touch

```
Rigidbody2D rb;
public float speed = 1f;
Vector2 curPos;

void Update () {
    curPos = transform.position;
}

void Awake () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector2 touchedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(touch.position.x, touch.position.y));
        switch (touch.phase) {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, touchedPos, Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, touchedPos, Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
            if (curPos != touchedPos) {
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, touchedPos, Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            } break;
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу понять в чем ошибка кода. Если я правильно понимаю логику работы TouchPhase то в момент окончания нажатия на экран проверяется условие равно ли текуще положение объекта точки касания. Если нет, то объект продолжает двигаться (ну по крайней мере должен). В итоге после того как я отпускаю палец, обьект перестает двигаться. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: попробуйте использовать просто Update, должно помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объект у вас двигается только при двух условиях.
1 момент касания.
2 палец двигается. И всё. Так-же сравнивать положение объекта и положение касания это безумие, они никогда не будут идеально соответствовать до целых и уж тем более до стотысячных долей. Зачем вам Rigidbody2D, если вы забив на физику перемещаете координаты объекта сами?

---

Да и вообще если объект следует за местом, где был тач, нет смысла проверять коснулся ли ты объекта, поскольку тем самым ты задаёшь ему новую позицию следования.

```
public float speed = 100f;
Vector2 targetPos;

void Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector2 touchedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(touch.position.x, touch.position.y));
        targetPos = touchedPos;
    }
    if (targetPos != Vector2.zero) {
        Vector2 MoveVector = targetPos-(Vector2)transform.position;
        if (MoveVector.magnitude < speed*Time.deltaTime) {
            transform.position = targetPos;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
        } else {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = MoveVector.normalized*speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ